# wifi子機のドライバー"carl9170"がコンパイルできない

Tags: makefile, kernel

家にあったcarl9170ドライバーを必要とするwifi子機を利用したいと思い、
   modinfo carl9170
と実行したところ、そのようなドライバはないと言われたので、
carl9170ドライバーを、kernel.orgのバージョン4.4.77のカーネルから取り出し、

```
make
```

と実行したところ、

```
make: *** ターゲットがありません.  中止.
```

と表示されてしまいました。
どうすればコンパイルできるのでしょうか。
･環境
CPU : arm64
カーネルバージョン : 4.4.77

Answer (score 1, accepted):

カーネルモジュールのビルド方法は、カーネルのソースの `Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt` に書いてあります。

以下のようにビルドできます。

```
luna:/tmp % cp -R /bak/linux-4.15.1/drivers/net/wireless/ath .
luna:/tmp % cd ath
luna:ath % make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$PWD
make: ディレクトリ '/usr/lib/modules/4.15.1-2-ARCH/build'　に入ります
(略)
make: ディレクトリ '/usr/lib/modules/4.15.1-2-ARCH/build' から出ます
luna:ath % ls -al carl9170/carl9170.ko 
-rw-r--r-- 1 masm users 185912  2月 12 16:38 carl9170/carl9170.ko
luna:ath %
```

もしビルドされなければ、make に `CONFIG_CARL9170=m CONFIG_ATH_COMMON=m` も付けてみてください。

正常にビルドできたら、

```
luna:ath % sudo make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$PWD modules_install
```

でインストールできると思います。

---

`cp: cannot stat './modules.order' No such file or directory` について。

どうすればその状態になるのか解りませんが、`make ... modules_install` の代わりに以下のようにして手動でインストールはできると思います。

1. `/lib/modules/4.4.77-rockchip-ayufan-136/extra` ディレクトリがなければ作ります

   ```
   sudo mkdir /lib/modules/4.4.77-rockchip-ayufan-136/extra
   ```
2. カーネルモジュールをコピーします

   ```
   sudo cp ath.ko /lib/modules/4.4.77-rockchip-ayufan-136/extra/
   sudo cp carl9170/carl9170.ko /lib/modules/4.4.77-rockchip-ayufan-136/extra/
   ```
3. modules.* を更新します。

   ```
   sudo depmod -A
   ```

また、失敗しているターゲットが `_modinst_` である点が気になります。
もし `/lib/modules/4.4.77-rockchip-ayufan-136/kernel` ディレクトリとその中身が、以前はあったが今はなくなっているなら、`make ... modules_install` によって消えてしまった可能性があります。
その場合、カーネルモジュールが入っているパッケージを再度インストールしてください。

Comment: make : *** /lib/modules4.4.77-rockchip-ayufan-136/build: No such file or directory. Stop. と表示されてしまいました。

Comment: OS が何なのかわかりませんが、カーネルモジュールをビルドする環境が入ってないです。`/lib/modules/4.4.77-rockchip-ayufan-136/build` がどれかのパッケージに含まれているはずですので、それをインストールしてください。

Comment: そういえば、コメントに書かれたディレクトリが `/lib/modules4.4.77...` となっています。`modules` の後に `/` がありません。コメントに書く時に間違えたのなら先程のコメントのとおりですが、そうでないのなら、入力するコマンドをミスしていますので入力しなおしてください。

Comment: 本当にありがとうございました!やはりmodules の後に /がないのが原因でした。無事にcarl9170.koが生成されました。 しかし、新たな問題が発生しました。

    sudo make -C /lib/modules/uname -r/build M=$PWD modules_install

と実行したところ、

    make : Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-kernel-headers-4.4.77-rockchip-ayufan-136'
    cp: cannot stat './modules.order' No such file or directory
    Makefile:1162: recipe for target '_modinst_' failed
    make: *** [_modinst_] Error 1
    make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.77-rockchip-ayufan-136'

と表示されてしまいました。
どうすればよいのでしょうか?

Comment: ありがとうございました。無事に認識するようになりました!

Comment: @wanwansan  回答の左側に ✓ マークがあると思います。この回答で解決したのでしたら、この ✓ マークをクリックしてください。「この回答で解決した」と宣言することになり、この質問を終了扱いとすることができます。

Answer (score -1):

[RaspberryPi - 無線LAN設定](http://masquaremo.github.io/blog/2013/02/04/231557/) のページに書かれていることを関係しませんか？
必要なのはドライバではなく、ファームウェアでは。

こういう質問は、「wifi子機」というような対象が判らない書き方ではなく、機器のメーカーと型番を明記したほうが適切な回答が得られやすいと思います。

Comment: 失礼しました。機器の型番は、NECのAterm WL300NU-Gです。私がコンパイルしたいのはドライバーです。合ってます。